# Angular6: Exported FormsModule not working

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-forms

So I'm importing and exporting FormsModule in a shared Module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ]
})
```

I import SharedModule into another module where I have component that does this in the template:

```
<app-validation-errors [formControlInput]="formControlInput" [validationModel]="validationModel"></app-validation-errors>
```

Which is this in the `ValidationErrorsComponent`

```
@Input()
formControlInput: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

However I'm getting this console error:

```
Can't bind to 'formControlInput' since it isn't a known property of 'app-validation-errors'.
```

Been messing aroudn with this for a while, hoping one of you guys can help me out.

Comment: Do you use it in lazy loaded module?

Comment: If yes, then I think you should import your shared module in your routing module.

Comment: nope no lazy loading going on.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using both FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule?

Comment: Got this working here ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwx2pt ... where are you importing Input from?

Comment: @danday74 Input is being imported from @angular/core

Comment: ok well not sure what prob is, try follow my stack blitz example